# How to associate a kernel module to a specific device (driver instance)?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, kernel

[dev-audio](http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/arch/arm/mach-s5pv210/dev-audio.c) declares two devices:

```
struct platform_device s5pv210_device_iis0 = {
 63         .name = "samsung-i2s",
 64         .id = 0,
 65         .num_resources    = ARRAY_SIZE(s5pv210_iis0_resource),
 66         .resource         = s5pv210_iis0_resource,
 67         .dev = {
 68                 .platform_data = &i2sv5_pdata,
 69         },
 70 };   
 76 static struct resource s5pv210_iis1_resource[] = {
 77         [0] = DEFINE_RES_MEM(S5PV210_PA_IIS1, SZ_256),
 78         [1] = DEFINE_RES_DMA(DMACH_I2S1_TX),
 79         [2] = DEFINE_RES_DMA(DMACH_I2S1_RX),
 80 };
 81 
 82 struct platform_device s5pv210_device_iis1 = {
 83         .name             = "samsung-i2s",
 84         .id               = 1,
 85         .num_resources    = ARRAY_SIZE(s5pv210_iis1_resource),
 86         .resource         = s5pv210_iis1_resource,
 87         .dev = {
 88                 .platform_data = &i2sv3_pdata,
 89         },
 90 };
 91 
 92 static struct resource s5pv210_iis2_resource[] = {
 93         [0] = DEFINE_RES_MEM(S5PV210_PA_IIS2, SZ_256),
 94         [1] = DEFINE_RES_DMA(DMACH_I2S2_TX),
 95         [2] = DEFINE_RES_DMA(DMACH_I2S2_RX),
 96 };
```

The two devices are 2 instances of the [i2s driver](http://lxr.hpcs.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/linux/sound/soc/samsung/i2s.c).

Assuming I add a function `EXPORT_SYMBOL` in [i2s driver](http://lxr.hpcs.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/linux/sound/soc/samsung/i2s.c), which will be used by 2 different kernel modules.

How can I declare and use such an exported function doing the following:

```
if (called from kernel module 1):
 i2s_rxctrl the device id=0
elif (called from kernel module 2):
 i2s_rxctrl the device id=1
```

There is one-to-one mapping of a kernel module to device id.

So basically what I ask is how to make the exported symbol to be `Object oriented style` so for each instance it will execute code specific to the device. I thought to give the kernel module an handle to  `*pdev` but it seems to be a violation.

Comment: I do not understand. Why you want to use a function in two different modules (two different drivers)? Or you mean two different instance that are using the same driver?

Comment: I want that each kernel module will interact with a different instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can always pass a parameter and value to your kernel module and check it in driver code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom structure with all necessary information to uniquely identify your instance across different modules (why not, also *pdev). Then, you pass this structure to your library. Thanks to your custom structure, the library can do the correct operation.

Comment: How is it different from what I suggested in my question?

Comment: You said to use _pdev_ but you think it is a violation. I think that only pdev, maybe, is not enough (I do not know your real problem). But, yes it is the same stuff, like @Shuduo answer: *pass a parameter and value* or whatever you want to identify the instance.

Comment: yeah both of answers are trivial, anyway thanks for your effort. apparently sometimes there is no a miracle solution in the kernel.

Comment: trivial is good if it works. It easy to do, easy to understand, less bugs. The miracle is that these easy solutions work :)